# How to define a Task into VS Code to execute npm install with parameters

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm, npm-install

I want to run `npm install` from a `VSCode Task` always with a set of command parameters, how can I put these parameters in the tasks.json (or anywhere else if that's needed)?

Comment: have you read the task page of VSC doc

Comment: I think so, this one you mean? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks I don't know if I can use the integrated npm tasks or if I need to build a custom one.

Answer (score 1):

As reference I have created a custom task as I was not able to find how to do it using npm tasks with the following simple tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "install",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "npm install --registry https://registry.npmjs.org",
            "detail": "install dependencies from package.json"
        }
    ]
}
```

Anyway that's not what I was looking for as I would like to use npm custom tasks so if anyone finds how to do it I would mark it as resolved, this does not solve my question.